# MVC 5 ajax post returns 404

Tags: ajax, post, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my ajax -

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',                
    url: 'SaveSomething',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                                
    data: JSON.stringify({ json: 'test' }),
     success: function (data) {
          console.log('SUCCESS || ' + data);
      },
      fail: function (data) {
          console.log('FAIL || ' + data);
      }
 });
```

Here is my controller -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSomething(string json)
{
     return View("Index", new ViewModel());
}
```

When I examine the request in developer tools, it is pointing to the correct url.  I've also tried changing the url to be more explicit -

```
url:  '/MyArea/MyController/MyAction'
```

but I continue to get the 404.  I have just the default routes defined - nothing crazy going on here.  I can change the request to a GET and clear out the data, and it hits the controller successfully.

Anyone have any thoughts why this won't go through?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JSON.stringify for your data. Just call:

```
data: { json: 'test' },
```

and it should work.

Comment: And remove the Content-type or change to: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Same result - 404.

Comment: this turned out to be a side affect of a security module elsewhere in my code.  Thanks for the help.